# form onkeyup value is not come on email id

Tags: php, jquery, html

The form onkeyup value is showing on webpage nicely but when i submit the form then this value is not come on my email ID

I want the input tag name="buyget" value in email id when its submit

There is some HTML code

```
<input name="buysend" type="text" class="form-control" id="GBP" onkeyup="gbpfunc()" size="10" >
<input name="buyget"  type="text" id="USD" size="10" onkeyup="usdfunc()" class="form-control" disabled>
```

There is some PHP Code

```
".$_REQUEST["buysend"]."
".$_REQUEST["buyget"]."
```

Look at the below link and try it on buyform, i need it asap

[Work on buy form](http://theroyalcourt.co/harshat/index.html)

Comment: I want the input tag name="buyget" value in emal id when its submit

Answer (score -1):

In HTML Source Code, change:

> Disabled to readonly

```
<input name="buyget"  type="text" id="USD" size="10" onkeyup="usdfunc()" class="form-control" readonly>
```